# For commutative arithmetic, why do we have 'asymmetrical' nomenclature like 'multiplier x multiplicand' and 'augend + addend'?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

I've noticed in the [Wikipedia page for multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication) that every basic operation has accumulated more than one set of names:

[image: arith Table]

With subtraction and division, I can see why it is necessary to have two distinct nouns, though I haven't seen the terms 'minuend' and 'subtrahend' used much. Since addition and multiplication are commutative, why do they have distinct terms for the left and right numbers? I've heard the terms 'multiplier' and 'multiplicand' before, but never 'augend' and 'addend'.

What's up with these baroque terms? Are these terms needlessly specific?

Comment: This is the first place I've ever seen "augend".

Answer (score 0):

If I asked you to imagine five apples plus two apples, you'd probably imagine having five apples, then adding another apple and another apple until there are two more apples. Why did you not imagine starting off with two apples, then adding five more, even though they're the same? That's because, while they mean the same thing, typically you'd imagine the operation acting from the second number upon the first number, which is why operands for commutative operations occasionally are reffered to with different names.